# PHP if statement: all conditions approved

Tags: php, if-statement

I've checked a condition in my script, but am having problems with the `if` statement. Please check my code:

```
function __construct($user=null)
    {
       parent::__construct();
       require_once 'model/chanell_model.php';
       $this->theme->msg='.....';
       $this->db = new chanell_model();
       if ($user==null && !parent::isLog()){
           $this->themes=2;
       }elseif ($user===null){
           echo 'print';
       $this->db->getChanellData();

       }elseif($user!==null){
           echo 'print';

       }else{
           $this->db->getChanellData($user);
    }
}
```

How could be possible in same time `$user == null` and also `$user != null`.
In this code both `echo` commands will work .

I've also used `==` instead of `===` .

Sorry for my English. Any help would be great.

Comment: ... What? Could you clarify the issue? `$user` can't be `NULL` and not `NULL` at the same time.

Comment: @Epodax         if ($user!=null){
            $this->db->getChanellData($user);
        }else{

            $this->db->getChanellData();
        }  in this code $this->db->getChanellData(); run 2 times

Comment: You are probably confused by multiple outputs because you create multiple objects. An `if elseif elseif ...` can only execute one of its blocks whatever condition you put.

Comment: @trincot yeah exactly , how can possible if  and else both work ?

Comment: @user3721234, I gave a hint: you are probably creating multiple objects and misinterpreting the output. Or else you have provided simplified code in your question that does not reproduce your problem. Add `echo "start";` at the start of the constructor, and `echo "end";` at the end, and see what the sequence of output is.

Comment: perhaps we are dealing with quantum code which can, like Schrodinger's cat, be both null and not null at the same time

Comment: @trincot problem is not my objects . i change  the code to this         if ($user===null){
            echo 'bye';
        }else{

            echo 'hi';
        } and it will print hi and bye

Comment: Please add the 2 x `echo` as I suggested and tell me what the sequence of output is. Look how you say you first get *hi* and then *bye*. Do you really think PHP is executing backwards? I am quite sure your code gets executed multiple times. Please add the `echo`s. You will get `start - hi - end - start - bye - end - ...`

Comment: @trincot startbyehiend

Comment: Did you put the braces like you have them in your question? Any warnings produced by PHP (I hope you are not suppressing them). Is there ***anything*** different in your code in that function than you have put in the question?

Comment: @trincot no all warnings are open. no thats all my code

Comment: ok guys thanks to all who help specialy trinco .

i dont know why but when i restart my apache every things become okay .

Answer (score 0):

Take a long breath

```
if ($user===null){ echo 'bye'; }else{ echo 'hi'; }
```

if this piece of code will write 'bye' and 'hi' at the same time, so it's time to change your computer... :)

More seriously,

Try to debug your code and [XDEBUG](https://xdebug.org/) will be your friend for life :)
And for the immediate test, you can run your constructor as follow

```
function __construct($user = NULL) {
        parent::__construct();
        require_once 'model/chanell_model.php';
        $this->theme->msg   =   '.....';
        $this->db           =   new chanell_model();

        $debug          = TRUE;
        $executionId    = uniqid();
        $debugMessage   = '';

        if ((is_null($user)) && (!parent::isLog())){
            $this->themes=2;

            if ($debug) {
                $debugMessage .= "First condition executed, id: <" . $executionId . ">\n";
            }
        }
        elseif ($user===null){
            echo 'print';
            $this->db->getChanellData();
            if ($debug) {
                $debugMessage .= "Second condition executed, id: <" . $executionId . ">\n";
            }
        }
        elseif($user!==null){
            echo 'print';
            if ($debug) {
                $debugMessage .= "Third condition executed, id: <" . $executionId . ">\n";
            }
        }
        else{
            $this->db->getChanellData($user);
            if ($debug) {
                $debugMessage .= "Fourth condition executed, id: <" . $executionId . ">\n";
            }
        }
        if ($debug) {
            print $debugMessage;
        }
    }
```

You will see, that the same execution id (simulated by uniid) can not run twice
Also :

- use `NULL` instead of `null`
- to test if value is null use `is_null()`
- Fourth condition will never run!!

Do not forget to remove the debug mess once you've finished

Comment: hi :D . i used xdebug always  :) anyway .is_null() output is correct . also use NULL  and nothing change :(